# Tracking history of a branch

Tags: git

How can I see the history of a particular branch?

I have been creating and merging branches. However, on one particular branch say for example `new_feature`. I want to know the history of what has been merged into this branch, and what branch this was created from?

The reason is I have this `new_feature` branch, and I want to know what other branches was merged into it, and what branch the `new_feature` was made from?

I an not really interested in using any GUI tools, maybe some on the command line.
I'm using Git version 1.7.5.4 and Ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git log --oneline --graph --all` may give you what you want, without the need for third-party tools.

- `--oneline` makes the commits display on one line only, instead of the longer default format.
- `--graph` shows branch/merge history with ASCII characters.
- `--all` shows all branches in the history, not just the current one.

Comment: Also this is very useful as well. git log --decorate=full

Comment: One day I'll go through all the git man pages. So many hidden gems. (Okay maybe it'll take more than a day…)

Comment: Should be `--all` instead of `-all`

Comment: Thanks for spotting that zihaoya, I've fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

You can see only merge commits with `git log --merges`. As long as you haven't messed with your merge commit messages, you'll see what branches you've merged. (If you don't want to use `HEAD` as a starting point, provide a commit/branch/tag as an argument.) Tweak the output to your liking with other options - see the man page. You might like `--oneline` (one line commit summaries) or even `--pretty=%s` (print only commit subjects). You might also like `--first-parent`, which by following only the first parents of merges, prevents it from reporting commits from the merged branches.

Knowing what branch a branch *started* from is a little trickier - that's not really information that gets recorded. You might find it as the first (bottom) entry in the output of `git reflog <branch>`, if it was recent enough.

Answer (score 2):

I often use [`tig`](http://jonas.nitro.dk/tig/), which is a text mode repository browser for Git. However, the `gitk` program that comes with Git is also useful for viewing repository history, because sometimes the lines between branches can get pretty complicated and it's easier to see in a GUI tool.

For low-level history, the `git reflog` command will show you all the actions that have caused the current (or specified) branch head to move.